# unordered list jquery shown selected item from list in fixed position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an unordered list. I have to select an item from the list and show it in a fixed space.

my problem is that always visualize the last element of the list and when i click on the others links the last one is always on the front side.

how can I visualize the element i select? 
my list is very long and I can't make hide command for all items.

http://jsfiddle.net/ymkccefd/

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#show1").click(function(){
    $("#one").show();
});
$("#show2").click(function(){
    $("#two").show();
});
  $("#show3").click(function(){
    $("#three").show();
});

});
```

```
<ul id="element">
        <li><div id="show1"> showElementOne </div> </li>
        <li><div id="show2"> showElementTwo</div>  </li>
        <li><div id="show3"> showElementThree</div> </li>
</ul>

<div id="one">  <img src="http://www.grandain.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/cane_1.jpg" height="402" width="420"> </div> 
<div id="two">  <img src="http://www.guidaprodotti.com/immagini/cane.jpg" height="420" width="420"> </div> 
<div id="three"> <img src="http://www.spaziosociale.it/public/immagini/22102014152877-canebar.jpg" height="420" width="420"> </div>

</body>
```

Comment: You need to be able to manipulate the other elements you don't want to show. Unless you have a global z-index variable that you dynamically update while modifying css, @dr_debugs method is a good option. You just have to copy and paste the class name into each list element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to hide the other Elements after clicking on your divs.

Change the Code like this:

1. `$("#show1").click(function(){
           $('.view').hide(); // add this to your code to hide your elemets again.
       $("#one").show();
   });`
2. So your list is very long and yout can't make hide command for all items:
   add the class `view` to your divs.

i updated your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ymkccefd/2/

Comment: easy and beautiful to see in the code! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `index` and add a wrapper around your images

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#element div").click(function() {
      $('.images div').hide();
      var index = $(this).parent().index();
      $(".images div").eq(index).show();
    });

  });
```

```css
.images div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="element">
  <li>
    <div id="show1">showElementOne</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div id="show2">showElementTwo</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div id="show3">showElementThree</div>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="images">
  <div id="one">
    <img src="http://www.grandain.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/cane_1.jpg" height="402" width="420">
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <img src="http://www.guidaprodotti.com/immagini/cane.jpg" height="420" width="420">
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    <img src="http://www.spaziosociale.it/public/immagini/22102014152877-canebar.jpg" height="420" width="420">
  </div>
</div>
```